# create four <img> that cover eachother 2v2

Tags: html, css

i have problem with img tag.
i have two responsive  img  with exactly position that i want.

The Code [ Images are circle and transparent [png] ]:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:auto; display:flex;">
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 8%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p1.png" />
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 0%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p2.png" /> 
</div>
```

i want to add two another responsive img for always cover my two img i made in above:

something like this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin:auto; display:flex;">
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 8%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p1.png" />
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 0%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p2.png" />
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 8%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p1-1.png" />
    <img style="margin-left: 0%;margin-top: 0%;height: 60%;object-fit: contain;" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/p2-2.png" />
</div>
```

but i don't have any idea for create them.
can you help me to handle it ?

Comment: Try adding `position:absolute;` to the imgs and `z-index` property to say who goes on top.

Comment: If you want any element to cover other elements, use `z-index`

Comment: you can declare the multiple images in `background-image`  in a div. if you only want to display the images as background. otherwise use `z-index` and `position:absolute`